# Android - Fused API getSpeed()

Tags: android, fusedlocationproviderapi, android-fusedlocation

By using fused API

1. I'm getting speed as `3.0` something. But I am in the same place and am not traveling anywhere, so from where is the speed coming from? I am testing with a Samsung device and a Motorola device. The problem is appearing on the Motorola device.
2. I'm setting the interval with: `mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000 * 60);` But the problem shows up on the Motorola device before 60 seconds which is updating (approximately at 30 second)

Comment: Anyone got any solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calculate like this,

1. Find distance between two points;

   ```
    private double distanceCalc(double lat1, double lon1, double lat2, double lon2, char unit) {
       if (lat1 == lat2 && lon1 == lon2) {
           return 0.0;
       } else {
           double theta = lon1 - lon2;
           double dist = Math.sin(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.sin(deg2rad(lat2)) + Math.cos(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(lat2)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(theta));
           dist = Math.acos(dist);
           dist = rad2deg(dist);
           dist = dist * 60 * 1.1515;
           if (unit == 'K') {
               dist = dist * 1.609344;
           } else if (unit == 'N') {
               dist = dist * 0.8684;
           }
           return (dist);
       }

   }
   ```

calculating as per the unit of kilometer.

```
 private double deg2rad(double deg) {
        return (deg * Math.PI / 180.0);
    }
```

This function converts decimal degrees to radians.

```
private double rad2deg(double rad) {
        return (rad * 180.0 / Math.PI);
    }
```

This function converts radians to decimal degrees.

2. To get speed,Calculate time difference between both and convert in to hours and speed as distance/time.Here i have done with km/h.